# FuelUX datagrid not loading (using example)

Tags: javascript, datagrid, fuelux

I'm new to FuelUX so I was trying to get this to work, based on the example provided:

```
require(['jquery','data.js', 'datasource.js', 'fuelux/all'], function ($, sampleData, StaticDataSource) {

    var dataSource = new StaticDataSource({
            columns: [{property:"memberid",label:"LidId",sortable:true},{property:"name",label:"Naam",sortable:true},{property:"age",label:"Leeftijd",sortable:true}],
            data: sampleData.memberdata,
            delay: 250
        });

        $('#MyGrid').datagrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            stretchHeight: true
        });

    });
});
```

With this as the data:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(factory);
    } else {
        root.sampleData = factory();
    }
}(this, function () {
    return {
        "memberdata": [{
            "memberid": 103,
            "name": "Laurens  Natzijl",
            "age": "25"
        }, {
            "memberid": 104,
            "name": "Sandra Snoek",
            "age": "25"
        }, {
            "memberid": 105,
            "name": "Jacob Kort",
            "age": "25"
        }, {
            "memberid": 106,
            "name": "Erik  Blokker",
            "age": "25"
        }, {
            "memberid": 107,
            "name": "Jacco  Ruigewaard",
            "age":"25"
        },{  /* etc */ }]
    }
}));
```

I've got no console errors, no missing includes. Everthing works just fine - it even looks like it's loading. Except nothing shows up in the datagrid but '0 items'.

Any suggestions? I think I did everything the example provided...

EDIT: 14:33 (Amsterdam)
There seems to be a difference when I put this in console:

**My page:**

```
require(['jquery','data.js','datasource.js', 'fuelux/all'], function ($, sampleData, StaticDataSource) {
    var dataSource = new StaticDataSource({
            columns: [{property:"memberid",label:"LidId",sortable:true},{property:"name",label:"Naam",sortable:true},{property:"age",label:"Leeftijd",sortable:true}],
            data: sampleData.memberdata,
            delay: 250
        });
    console.debug(dataSource);
});
```

1st row in console:

```
function localRequire(deps, callback, errback) { /* etc */ }
```

2nd row in console:

```
StaticDataSource {_formatter: undefined, _columns: Array[3], _delay: 250, _data: Array[25], columns: function…}
```

**FuelUX Example:**

```
require(['jquery', 'sample/data', 'sample/datasource', 'sample/datasourceTree', 'fuelux/all'], function ($, sampleData, StaticDataSource, DataSourceTree) {
    var dataSource = new StaticDataSource({
        columns: [{property: 'toponymName',label: 'Name',sortable: true}, {property: 'countrycode',label: 'Country',sortable: true}, {property: 'population',label: 'Population',sortable: true}, {property: 'fcodeName',label: 'Type',sortable: true}],
        data: sampleData.geonames,
        delay: 250
    });
    console.debug(dataSource);
});
```

1st row in console:

```
StaticDataSource {_formatter: undefined, _columns: Array[4], _delay: 250, _data: Array[146], columns: function…}
```

2nd row in console:

```
function (deps, callback, errback, relMap) { /* etc */ }
```

Maybe this will help you help me :)

Answer (score 7):

I didn't see all of the information I needed to provide a finite answer. The real magic is the datasource.js file (which you had not provided).

I thought an easier way of demonstrating all the necessary pieces would be to put together a JSFiddle showing your data in use and all the pieces that were necessary.

[Link to JSFiddle of Fuel UX Datagrid sample with your data](http://jsfiddle.net/bdeanet/WMHcu/)

Adam Alexander, the author of the tool, also has written a valuable example of using the dataGrid [DailyJS Fuel UX DataGrid](http://dailyjs.com/2012/10/29/fuel-ux/)

```
// DataSource Constructor
var StaticDataSource = function( options ) {
this._columns = options.columns;
this._formatter = options.formatter;
this._data = options.data;
this._delay = options.delay;
};

StaticDataSource.prototype = {
columns: function() {
    return this._columns
},
data: function( options, callback ) {
    var self = this;

    var data = $.extend(true, [], self._data);

    // SEARCHING
    if (options.search) {
        data = _.filter(data, function (item) {
            for (var prop in item) {
                if (!item.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
                if (~item[prop].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(options.search.toLowerCase())) return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

    var count = data.length;

    // SORTING
    if (options.sortProperty) {
        data = _.sortBy(data, options.sortProperty);
        if (options.sortDirection === 'desc') data.reverse();
    }

    // PAGING
    var startIndex = options.pageIndex * options.pageSize;
    var endIndex = startIndex + options.pageSize;
    var end = (endIndex > count) ? count : endIndex;
    var pages = Math.ceil(count / options.pageSize);
    var page = options.pageIndex + 1;
    var start = startIndex + 1;

    data = data.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

    if (self._formatter) self._formatter(data);

    callback({ data: data, start: 0, end: 0, count: 0, pages: 0, page: 0 });
}
};
```

If you were to provide your markup and what your "datasource.js" file contains, I may be able to help you further.

I think the demonstration provides much information on any pieces you may not have understood.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used the default with the filter stripped out. Your fiddle example works fine. However, I was requirejs. So it didn't fix it. But I'll still use your solution. Thanx.

Comment: I'm gonna try to see if I like this better. Then I'll decide if I'll accept it as the answer ~ ok? Thanx again!

Comment: What you can do is use the code in the answer above in place of your "datasource.js" file in the require dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to creatovisguru's answer:

In his JSFiddle example, pagination is broken. To fix it, change the following line:

```
callback({ data: data, start: start, end: end, count: count, pages: pages, page: page });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, when tried to integrate with Django. The issue I believe is on this line :

require(['jquery','data.js','datasource.js', 'fuelux/all'], function ($, sampleData, StaticDataSource) {

I was not able to specify file extension, my IDE (pycharm), would mark "red", when used "data.js", so it needs to stay without an extension, such as  "sample/data"

What I end up doing to make it work, is downloading the full fuelux directory from github in /var/www/html on a plain Apache setup ( no django, to avoid URL.py issues for static files ) and everything works using their example. Here are the steps to get you started :

cd /var/www/html
git clone https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux.git
and you will end up with fuelux in /var/www/html/fuelux/

in your browser, navigate to : http://foo.com/fuelux/index.html ( assuming your default document root is /var/www/html )

good luck!